# How can I build Entity Framework queries dynamically?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, filter, filtering

I'm quite new to Entity Framework and I have a question about filtering data.

I have two various Log entities, they are: `DiskLog` and `NetworkLog`. These entities both are derived from `Log` entity. Here is some code from my C# app:

```
public class Log { ... }
public class DiskLog : Log { ... }
public class NetworkLog : Log { ... }

public enum LogType
{
    NotInitialized = 0,
    Disk,
    Network
}

public List<Log> GetWithFilter(
    Guid userKey, 
    int nSkip, 
    int nTake, 
    DateTime dateFrom = DateTime.MinValue, 
    DateTime dateTo = DateTime.MaxValue, 
    LogType logType = LogType.NotInitialized, 
    int computerId = 0)
{
    // need to know how to optimize ...

    return ...
}
```

Of course, I already have working app and database tables created. What I want to do is to make function GetWithFilter work. I have several execution ways there:

1. `if logType == LogType.Disk && computerId <= 0` (it means there is no need to use computerId parameter in the query, select DiskLog entities only)
2. `if logType == LogType.Disk && computerId > 0` (means I have to use computerId parameter, select DiskLog entities only)
3. `if logType == LogType.NotInitialized && computerId <= 0` (no need to use computerId and logType, just select all the entities, DiskLog and NetworkLog)
4. `if logType == LogType.NotInitialized && computerId > 0` (select all types of logs for specified computer)
5. `if logType == LogType.Network && computerId <= 0` (select all NetworkLog entities)
6. `if logType == LogType.Network && computerId > 0` (select all NetworkLog entities for specified computer)

As you can see, there are plenty of available options. And I got to write 6 queries like this:

1.

```
context.LogSet
    .OfType<DiskLog>
    .Where(x => x.Computer.User.UserKey == userKey)
    .Where(x => x.DateStamp >= dateFrom && x.DateStamp < dateTo)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
    .Skip(nSkip)
    .Take(nTake)
    .ToList();
```

2.

```
context.LogSet
    .OfType<DiskLog>
    .Where(x => x.Computer.User.UserKey == userKey)
    .Where(x => x.DateStamp >= dateFrom && x.DateStamp < dateTo)
    .Where(x => x.Computer.Id == computerId)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
    .Skip(nSkip)
    .Take(nTake)
    .ToList();
```

3.

```
context.LogSet
    .Where(x => x.Computer.User.UserKey == userKey)
    .Where(x => x.DateStamp >= dateFrom && x.DateStamp < dateTo)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
    .Skip(nSkip)
    .Take(nTake)
    .ToList(); // simplest one!
```

4.

```
context.LogSet
    .Where(x => x.Computer.User.UserKey == userKey)
    .Where(x => x.DateStamp >= dateFrom && x.DateStamp < dateTo)
    .Where( x => x.Computer.Id == computerId)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
    .Skip(nSkip)
    .Take(nTake)
    .ToList();
```

5.

```
context.LogSet
    .OfType<NetworkLog>
    .Where(x => x.Computer.User.UserKey == userKey)
    .Where(x => x.DateStamp >= dateFrom && x.DateStamp < dateTo)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
    .Skip(nSkip)
    .Take(nTake)
    .ToList();
```

6.

```
context.LogSet
    .OfType<NetworkLog>
    .Where(x => x.Computer.User.UserKey == userKey)
    .Where(x => x.DateStamp >= dateFrom && x.DateStamp < dateTo)
    .Where( x => x.Computer.Id == computerId)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
    .Skip(nSkip)
    .Take(nTake)
    .ToList();
```

So the question is how can I optimize the code? Where is the way to make it better.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can easily use query compossition.

You first start with query.

```
IQueryable<Log> query = context.LogSet;
```

They you compose sub-queries.

```
if (logType == LogType.Disk)
{
    query = query.OfType<DiskLog>(); // not sure if you need conversion here
} 
else if (logType == LogType.Network)
{
    query = query.OfType<NetworkLog>(); // not sure if you need conversion here
}

query = query.Where(x => x.Computer.User.UserKey == userKey);

if (computerId != 0)
   query = query.Where( x => x.Computer.Id == computerId);

// .. and so on

query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Skip(nSkip).Take(nTake);

return query.ToList(); // do database call, materialize the data and return;
```

And I would recomend using nullable value types for cases, when there is no value.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Func<T,bool>` to optimize this

```
IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> userKeyFunc, Func<T, bool> dateFunc, int skip, int take)
{
    return source.OfType<T>().Where(userKeyFunc).Where(dateFunc).Skip(skip).Take(take);
}
```

Then use:

```
var result = Select<NetworkLog>(context.LogSet,x => x.Computer.User.UserKey == userKey,
                                x => x.DateStamp >= dateFrom && x.DateStamp < dateTo, nSkip,nTake)
```

And you can create factory for this functions

Comment: That should be Expression<Func ..>. This will filter the data in-memory.