# LINQ to SQL Condition

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

HI!

I want to make a LINQ to SQL request that handles two different conditions. One of them is listed in the function below. The condition I want to include in the function below is that I want to be able to request persons of any age. How do I rewrite this functions so it handles a request for 1. Persons of a certain age or 2: Persons of any age.

```
 public IQueryable test(int age)

    {

        var persons = from p in db.Person

                      where p.age = age

                      select new

                      {

                          p.name

                      };



        return persons;

    }
```

Comment: Any reason why you're using an anonymous type for a single value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var persons = from p in db.Person
select new                      
{                          
    p.name,
    p.age
};

if (age > 0) // or declare a bool to check age needs to be filtered.
{
    persons = persons.Where(p => p.age == age);
}
```

Comment: With this query you get always all persons from the database. Maybe not good for performance.

Comment: Performance hasn't currently been specified as an issue; this would be my preferred method for readability/maintainability until it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
public IQueryable test(Nullable<int> age)
{ 
      var persons = from p in db.Person

                  where p.age = age.HasValue ? age.Value : p.age

                  select new

                  {

                      p.name

                  };

    return persons;

}
```

If you pass `null` to this function you will get persons of any age.

Comment: This is the same as the SQL statement age = ISNULL(@age,age)

Comment: where p.age == (age.HasValue ? age.Value : p.age)

Answer (score 0):

1. Write two queries.
2. Use [query composition.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881107/how-can-i-build-entity-framework-queries-dynamically/5882243#5882243)